# Word for a short exhalation, antonym of "gasp"?

Tags: single-word-requests

When you're disappointed or upset and rather than say anything you make a short exhalation, how's that called? It's sort of as if you said 'huh' while looking at the floor standing next to the person who have just upset you, but just without saying it.

/Think the "sniker" is what I was after. Thanks everybody.

Comment: Are you asking for an antonym?

Comment: Closed captioning generally renders it as "[scoffs]" but I think that is only really appropriate if the feeling expressed is disdain, which by no means is always the case when that caption appears. "Sigh" tends to refer to a gentler exhalation, not a staccato one.

Comment: "sigh" is not it. I'm going for a very short exhalation, expressing contained anger. "Scoff" could be the word. Does it mean a short exhalation though?

Comment: I don't know what a "sniker" is. Care to share? Anyway, I'm thinking you're talking about a "huff", which is a short exhalation.

Comment: @JEL, [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/huff#Noun) lists huff as "A heavy breath; a grunt or sigh," which is not what I need. Sniker is [explained](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/snicker#Noun) as "A stifled or broken laugh," or to emit that kind of short laugh, which I think if perfect for what I was looking for.

Comment: _Harrumph._ A grumpy expression of dissatisfaction or disapproval.

Comment: 'Snicker' I'm familiar with. It's a type of laughter. As for 'huff', I suppose a 'puff' is the lighter version, if that's what you're after.

Answer (score 4):

You could try [***snort***](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/snort)

Defined by [Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/misc/HarperCollinsProducts.aspx?English)<sup>1</sup> as:

> 1. (Physiology) (intr) to exhale forcibly through the nostrils, making a characteristic noise
> 2. (intr) (of a person) to express contempt or annoyance by such an exhalation
> 3. (tr) to utter in a contemptuous or annoyed manner

<sup>1</sup><sub><sup>Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged © HarperCollins Publishers 1991, 1994, 1998, 2000, 2003</sup></sub>

Answer (score 0):

**a brief sigh** might be an answer.

> - [**sigh**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=column+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VmcRVvikK4eEwATOwpyoDA&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=sigh+definition) -  (noun) -  a long, deep, audible exhalation expressing sadness, relief, tiredness, or a similar feeling.
> - [**sigh**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=column+definition&rls=com.microsoft:pt-BR:%7Breferrer:source?%7D&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&sourceid=ie7&rlz=1I7ADFA_pt-BRBR488&gfe_rd=cr&ei=VmcRVvikK4eEwATOwpyoDA&gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=sigh+definition) - (verb) - emit a long, deep, audible breath expressing sadness, relief, tiredness, or a similar feeling.
>
> e.g.
>
> ""[A brief sigh](http://www.asiapress.org/rimjin-gang/archives/2015/04/06225812.html) of relief for North Koreans
>
> "she let out a long sigh of despair"
>
> "Harry sank into a chair and sighed with relief"

Comment: thanks, but I'm not looking for word that means a long deep breath, looking for one that means a very short exhalation.

Comment: @user498283 A "brief sigh" is current usage.

Comment: It should by no means represent relief. It should represent that a person could lash out at you at the moment but trying their best to let it go. Imagine a situation where one guy says "I always knew you were no good". In response, the second one just exhales with a fake smile, while looking down, as if to say "One more word and you're really going to regret it"

Comment: @user498283 When you sigh, you exhale. That’s what a sigh is. See the synonyms of “sigh” [here.](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sigh)